# Метод с рекурсией

Tags: c#, рекурсия, методы

Следующий код печатает цифры данного числа. Работает без проблем, все правильно. Когда я прогоняю его шаг за шагом он срезает цифры один за другим до последней цифры (5), печатает его, и возвращается к вызывающему методу. В этот момент n=5. При следущей рекурсии он заходит в метод с n=56, n=567, и тд. здесь я не понимаю, как рекурсия начинает добавлять цифры в обратном порядке. Если-б кто-нибудь смог мне объяснить пожалуйста. Я понимаю как эти цифры потом распечатываются.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
            Console.Write("\n\n Recursion : Display the individual digits of a given number :\n");
            Console.Write("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            int num = 567234;
            Console.Write(" The digits in the number {0} are : ", num);
        
        separateDigits(num);         
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

     static void separateDigits(int n)
    {            
        if (n < 10)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}  ", n);
            return;
        }            
        separateDigits(n / 10);
        Console.Write(" {0} ", n % 10);            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно понять для начала 2 операции

/ - целочисленное деление

% - остаток от деления

далее

```
    if (n < 10) // условие для остановки рекурсии
    {
        Console.Write("{0}  ", n);
        return;
    }            
    separateDigits(n / 10); // разделить n на 10 и передать рекурсивно
    Console.Write(" {0} ", n % 10); // напечатать остаток от деления
```

Так ват печатает в обратном порядке потому что функция у ходит в рекурсию до вывода значения остатка. Если поменять местами

```
    Console.Write(" {0} ", n % 10); // напечатать остаток от деления
    separateDigits(n / 10); // разделить n на 10 и передать рекурсивно
```

то получите прямой порядок

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас понял где я недопонимал. При рекурсии мы последовательно идем во внутр метода, снова и снова, до последней цифры. Как в матрешках. При этом оставляя на каждом уровне различные значения n, так как они имеют различные scop-ы. Таким образом, ответ на мой вопрос n равен 56 потому,что рекурсия пошла обратно на верхний метод, где мы оставили n=56. Aziz Umarov, катта рахмат за то, что помогли мне это понять.

Comment: Если ответ помог то можете его пометить как полезный. Галочка под стрелками